# Closed form , series ... help please

Tags: sequences-and-series

*i'm in a collage , studying sequence and series.*

**Prednisone is often prescribed for acute asthma attacks. For 5 mg tablets, typical instructions are: “Take 8 tablets the first day, 7 the second, and decrease by one tablet each day until all tablets are gone.” Prednisone decays exponentially in the body, and 24 hours after taking k mg, there are kx mg in the body.**

**(a) Write formulas involving x for the amount of prednisone in the body**

the exponential decay is formed http://www.freemathhelp.com/forum/attachment.php?attachmentid=2602&stc=1

so i think ...

...........**(i) 24 hours after taking the first dose (of 8 tablets), right before taking the second dose (of 7 tablets)**

is the answer "8*5e^(-kx)" ? ....i don't know what k is.

...........**(ii) Immediately after taking the second dose (of 7 tablets).**

"8*5e^(-kx)+ 7*5e^(-kx)" ?

...........**(iii) Immediately after taking the third dose (of 6 tablets).**

"8*5e^(-kx)+ 7*5e^(-kx)+ 6*5e^(-kx)" ?

...........**(iv) Immediately after taking the eighth dose (of 1 tablet).**

"8*5e^(-kx)+ 7*5e^(-kx)+ 6*5e^(-kx) + ... + e^(-kx)" ?

...........**(v) 24 hours after taking the eighth dose.**

i don't know how to find it.

...........**(vi) n days after taking the eighth dose.**

i don't know how to find it.

**(b) Find a closed form for the sum T = 8x^7+ 7x^6 + 6x^5 + ••• + 2x + 1, which is the number of prednisone tablets in the body immediately after taking the eighth dose.**

Tn = nx^(n-1) ??

**(c) If a patient takes all the prednisone tablets as prescribed, how many days after taking the eighth dose is there less than 3% of a prednisone tablet in the patient's body? The half-life of prednisone is about 24 hours.**

i don't know how to find it.

**(d) A patient is prescribed n tablets of prednisone the first day, n - 1 the second, and one tablet fewer each day until all tablets are gone. Write a formula that represents Tn, the number of prednisone tablets in the body immediately after taking all tablets. Find a closed form sum for Tn.**

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people are much more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself. Also, many would consider your post rude because it is a command ("Write..."), not a request for help, so please consider rewriting it.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  The line $24$ hours after taking $k$ mg you have $kx$ mg gives you the answer to a).  You have $40$ mg at the start, so you have $40x$ after $24$ hours.  Then you take $35$ more, so you have what?  Then a day wait multiplies by $x$ again, and so on.

for b:  do you know how to sum the geometric series $1+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots x^8$?  Do you see your series as the derivative of this.

For c:  you are now given that $x=\frac 12$

Comment: Thank you ... 

(((A)))
 i)40x 
ii)40x+35
iii)(40x+35)x + 30 = 40x^2 + 35x + 30
iv)40x^8 + 35x^7 + 30x^6 + ...

Answer (score 1):

We do the "closed form" part, for the general case d). If  $n$ pills are taken on the first day, $n-1$ on the second day, and so on, then immediately after the last pill there are $5(1+2x+3x^2+\cdots +nx^{n-1})$ milligrams in the body. Let's forget about the $5$, we can multiply by it at the end. So let
$$S(x)=1+2x+3x^2+\cdots +(n-1)x^{n-2}+ nx^{n-1}.$$

We will put $S(x)$ in a closed form probably close to what is expected.
Note that 
$$xS(x)=x+2x^2+3x^3+\cdots+(n-1)x^{n-1}+ nx^n.$$
Subtract $xS(x)$ from $S(x)$. We get
$$(1-x)S(x)=1+x+x^2+\cdots +x^{n-1}-nx^nx^8.\tag{$1$}$$
We may recognize $1+x+x^2+\cdots +x^{n-1}$  as the sum of a finite geometric series. This sum is $\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$ (if $x\ne 1$).  Thus from $(1)$ we see that
$$(1-x)S(x)=\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}-nx^n.$$
Divide both sides by $1-x$. We get 
$$S(x)=\frac{1-x^n}{(1-x)^2}-\frac{nx^n}{1-x}.$$
We can if we wish bring the above expression to the common denominator $(1-x)^2$.